# Execute javascript code on postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, webforms

I know that $(document).ready() executes code when the page is loaded, but may I achieve that the same execution plan with a function? For example I have a function "ShowSomething(para1, para2)" How can i execute this function after postback with the given parameters when the document is ready? I figured a way to do it, but I lose my parameters.

```
if (typeof showMessage != 'function') {
    window.showMessage = function () {
        $(document).ready(function (imgUrl, msg) {
                try {
                     pic1 = new Image(100, 25);
                     pic1.src = imgUrl;
                } catch (err) { }

                $("[id*='imgMsg']").attr("src", imgUrl);
                $("[id*='lblMsg']").html(msg);
                $("[id*='msgModal']").show(200);
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by after postback?

Comment: Postbacks clear javascript. You'll have to either request a hidden from on postback that contains your parameters or store your parameters in a session variable or in another manner.

Comment: Do you mean to do that : http://jsfiddle.net/m6zdubhk/1/?

Comment: Similar, but needs to happen only on .net postback. If I make a request to the server, the page comes back reloaded and execute this function only on specific occasions like clicking the Save button, but not the cancel button. The execution should happen only when the button is clicked (the request goes and comes back) and the whole document is loaded. If the document is not loaded the modal doesn't show up. So I need to modify the code up there so that the ready function to receive the 2 exposed parameters. Right now it works, but it doesn't receive the parameters.